# Dynamic Allocation for Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, dynamic-allocation, apache-spark-2.0, apache-spark-1.6

I have a Spark Streaming job running on our cluster with other jobs(Spark core jobs). I want to use Dynamic Resource Allocation for these jobs including Spark Streaming. According to below JIRA Issue, Dynamic Allocation is not supported Spark Streaming(in 1.6.1 version). But is Fixed in 2.0.0

[JIRA link](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12133?jql=project%20%3D%20SPARK%20AND%20text%20~%20%22streaming%20dynamic%22)

According to the PDF in this issue, it says there should be a configuration field called
`spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`
But I dont see this configuration in the documentation.

Can anyone please confirm,

1. Can't I enable dynamic resource allocation for Spark Streaming in 1.6.1 version.
2. Is it available in Spark 2.0.0 . If yes, what configuration should be set
   (`spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true` or `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`)

Answer (score 10):

> Can I enable Dynamic Resource Allocation for Spark Streaming for
> 1.6.1 version?

**Yes, you can enable** by setting up dynamic allocation to any spark application with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`
But I have few issues with streaming application(mentioned in [SPARK-12133](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12133))

1. Your executors may never be idle since they run something every N seconds
2. You should have at least one receiver running always
3. The existing heuristics don't take into account length of batch queue

So, they are added new property(`spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled`) in Spark 2.0 for streaming apps alone.

> Is it available in Spark 2.0.0 . If yes, what configuration should be
> set spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled or
> spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled ?

Must be `spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled` if the application is streaming one, otherwise go head with `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled`

**Edit:** (as per comment on 2017-JAN-05)

This is not documented as of today, But I get this property and implementation at Spark source code. [github: `ExecutorAllocationManager.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/ExecutorAllocationManager.scala#L189) (Unit tests [github: `ExecutorAllocationManagerSuite.scala`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.0/streaming/src/test/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/scheduler/ExecutorAllocationManagerSuite.scala#L32)) class has been included in Spark 2.0 and this implementation is not there in Spark 1.6 and below.

Comment: Thanks Srinivas for your reply. But I do not see "spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enabled" in the Spark Documentation. Can you please point me to the link where you saw this.

Comment: I am running spark cluster as standalone and there my cluster start with launching all the executor while I want to start that with minimum executors how to do that .. could you help with this and any reference which I can refer

Comment: also there is noting like "spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors" for streaming dynamic allocation