# spark streaming kafka issue while streaming is started

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to read data from kafka consumer using spark2-shell.

Please find my code below.

I start my spark2-shell in below way:

```
spark2-shell --jars kafka-clients-0.10.1.2.6.2.0-205.jar, spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11-2.1.1.jar
```

And please find my below code:

```html
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.InputDStream
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka010.{ConsumerStrategies, KafkaUtils, LocationStrategies}
import spark.implicits._

val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(2))

val topics = List("testingtopic01")

val preferredHosts = LocationStrategies.PreferConsistent

val kafkaParams = Map(
    "bootstrap.servers" -> "localhost:9192",
    "key.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "value.deserializer" -> classOf[StringDeserializer],
    "security.protocol" -> "SASL_PLAINTEXT",
    "auto.offset.reset" -> "earliest",
    "group.id" -> "spark-streaming-consumer-group"
  )

  
  
val lines = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, String](
      ssc,
      preferredHosts,
      ConsumerStrategies.Subscribe[String, String](topics.distinct, kafkaParams)
    )
 
lines.print()

ssc.start()
```

But after I start spark-streaming nothing shows up here.

```
scala> ssc.start() 
18/12/19 15:50:07 WARN streaming.StreamingContext:DynamicAllocation is enabled for this application.Enabling Dynamic allocation for Spark Streaming applications can cause data loss if Write Ahead Log is not enabled for non-replayable sources like Flume. See the programming guide for details on how to enable the Write Ahead Log.
```

Please suggest me a way to bypass this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should set spark.streaming.dynamicAllocation.enable=false. 
for more explaination you can visit to 
[Dynamic Allocation for Spark Streaming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41292880/dynamic-allocation-for-spark-streaming)